# Facebook page tab iframe appears on bottom

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

It seems like there's a bug with the facebook page tabs. Lots of them are rendering content on the bottom of the page.

Is there a change that developers must be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in fact a bug. I've just spent an hour looking into it.

It appears that they have increased the width of the right pane and it has caused the content area to shrink to less than 520px.

Unfortunately, the iframe that Facebook uses to display app content is hardcoded with a 520px width and you are unable to modify it. Need to wait till Facebook pushes out an update.

Edit: Bug reported to facebook already. Details [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298512163544012?browse=search_4f3c5c801a70d4639459595)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is FB wide on all pages. All of our iframe apps have this issue, including Coke, Chevy, etc. FB just finished a push minutes ago http://developers.facebook.com/live_status/ and I hope that they're fixing this right now!

Answer (score 0):

Problem still persists. There is a bug listed on Facebook http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298512163544012?browse=search_4f3c5c801a70d4639459595. I hope it gets prioritized.

Answer (score 0):

yup Facebook have stuffed up

Someone needs to fire the dev who committed these changes without testing them.....

Answer (score 0):

Well my apps shrink to fit any width. My apps can fit as small as 100 pixels w to 1000 pixels. Therefore its not a width issue. I'm just happy its nothing on my end I was freaking out for a second. Even restarted the computer (LOL) whew!!!